# Extracting a specific PIECE of a line from a textfile(Python)

Tags: python

I have a textfile with the format:

```
3rd Year:

MECN3010 PREREQ MECN2011 COREQ TIMES1 TIMES2 MO3, MO4, FR5, TH1, TH2

MECN3012 PREREQ MECN2012 COREQ TIMES1 TUA, WE3, TH1, TH2 TIMES2
```

How can i extract just a particular part of a line?

For e.g. suppose I want to extract just the

```
PREREQ MECN 2011
```

part from the 2nd line.

I'm able to read the particular line I want in, but I don't know how to `split` / `strip` just the info I need.

Comment: How do you know what part of the line you want?  In other words, what defines the bounds of the piece you're looking for?  The number of characters from the start of the line?  The *n* th "word" if separating the line by spaces, etc.

Comment: e.g. use `data.split()[0]` to extract the first field. `split()` works on whitespace per default

Comment: I think the number of characters from the start of the line since the entire file has the same format. So basically, I want to extract the piece of the line starting from just after 'PREREQ' until just before 'COREQ'

Comment: Is there a way for me to check how many fields there are in a particular line?

Comment: You have to know your separators. If you know them yes there is a way. Perhaps you could have a look at my regex-based answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you've found the line you're interested in:

```
line = "MECN3010 PREREQ MECN2011 COREQ TIMES1 TIMES2 MO3, MO4, FR5, TH1, TH2"
```

You have a few ways to extract a given field:

**1) Token-based**

```
>>> tokens = line.split()
>>> tokens
['MECN3010', 'PREREQ', 'MECN2011', 'COREQ', 'TIMES1', 'TIMES2', 'MO3,', 'MO4,', 'FR5,', 'TH1,', 'TH2']
>>> tokens[2]
'MECN2011'
>>> tokens[5]
'TIMES2'
```

Basically, you first split the line into a list of tokens (here done with `split()`), then select the one you are interested in with basic list indexing.

If you're interested in multiple tokens, you can slice them out and re-join them:

```
>>> ' '.join(tokens[1:3])
'PREREQ MECN2011'
```

**2) Position-based**

```
>>> line[16:24]
'MECN2011'
>>> line[38:44]
'TIMES2'
```

If the parts of the line you are looking for are at a known offset from the beginning of the line, you can use the iterable slicing syntax.

**3) Regex**

```
>>> re.search(r'(TIMES\d)', line).groups()
('TIMES1',)
>>> re.findall(r'TIMES\d', line)
['TIMES1', 'TIMES2']
```

This is a bit more advanced, and full coverage of this is outside the scope, but [here's the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't quite understand the regex method but the other two are just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If all the lines you are interested in contain `PREREQ MECNYYYY` where `YYYY` is the year number, you can use a regular expression like in the following:

**EDIT:** corrected the code

```
import re
# assume that line holds your text line
regex = ur'PREREQ MECN\d{4}'
matcher = re.search(re.compile(regex), line)
    if (matcher):
        match = matcher.group() #gives the actual match
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.rsplit) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.join).

```
lines = '''3rd Year:
MECN3010 PREREQ MECN2011 COREQ TIMES1 TIMES2 MO3, MO4, FR5, TH1, TH2
MECN3012 PREREQ MECN2012 COREQ TIMES1 TUA, WE3, TH1, TH2 TIMES2'''

for line in lines.splitlines()[1:]:
    print " ".join(line.split()[1:3])
```